# Transferring data from R to pandas using hdf5

Tags: python, r, pandas, hdf5

I have a data set in R that I'd like to work with in Python. For compatibility, it seems best to save the data in the hdf5 format in R and then load it in python using `pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore`. Below is the code to generate the hdf5 object from R.

```
library(rhdf5)
mat = matrix(data = rexp(200, rate = 10), nrow = 10, ncol = 10)
colnames(mat) = c(1:10)
rownames(mat)= c('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','K')
vec = c(1:10)
xx = list(mat=mat, vec=vec)
h5save(xx, file='xx.h5')
```

However, when I try to load this in pandas, the store.keys() is empty and accessing the contained object directly throws an error:

```
from pandas.io.pytables import HDFStore
store = HDFStore('xx.h5')
store.keys() # returns []
```

When I try to .get('xx'), the error is different from when I supply an invalid object name:

```
store.get('xx')
# TypeError: cannot create a storer if the object is not existing nor a value are passed
store.get('invalid')
# KeyError: 'No object named invalid in the file'
```

Loading the hdf5 file in R works perfectly fine.

Is there any (easy) way to fix the file loading in pandas? Alternatively, I'd also be fine with any solution that allows me to transfer R objects to pandas.

---

**edit:** file details below

```
$ ptdump-2.7 -av xx.h5 
/ (RootGroup) ''
  /._v_attrs (AttributeSet), 0 attributes
/xx (Group) ''
  /xx._v_attrs (AttributeSet), 0 attributes
/xx/mat (CArray(10, 10), zlib(7)) ''
  atom := Float64Atom(shape=(), dflt=0.0)
  maindim := 0
  flavor := 'numpy'
  byteorder := 'little'
  chunkshape := (10, 10)
  /xx/mat._v_attrs (AttributeSet), 0 attributes
/xx/vec (CArray(10,), zlib(7)) ''
  atom := Int32Atom(shape=(), dflt=0)
  maindim := 0
  flavor := 'numpy'
  byteorder := 'little'
  chunkshape := (10,)
  /xx/vec._v_attrs (AttributeSet), 0 attributes
```

Comment: can you post a ``ptdump -av <file>``?

Comment: This is not supported by ``HDFStore`` with ``CArray`` (it could be just is not implemented). However, if you can write the as a ``Table`` that will be readable. See the (here)[http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#external-compatibility], this link is about exporting.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'm not sure if that's possible from within R, and Google doesn't turn up anything on the topic.

Comment: I believe the ``rhdf5`` package can do this

Comment: If you tell me how I'll gladly accept is as an answer. There is a DataFrameAsCompound flag that can be used in conjunction with h5write but I always get a "unused arguments (DataFrameAsCompound = T)" warning.

Comment: no idea....don't really use R